# How to choose the highest score from 4 players?

Tags: java, android

I have a situation where i want to get a list (on button click) of scores (new Activity) of 4 players listed (1. Name - score 2. Name - score etc.) from high score to low score. Here is my code from Activity where i am sending names and scores to Activity 2.

```
Button calculate4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate4);
        calculate4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FourCalculate.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("name1", name1.getText().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("name2", name2.getText().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("name3", name3.getText().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("name4", name4.getText().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("p1", p1.getText().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("p2", p2.getText().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("p3", p3.getText().toString());
                myIntent.putExtra("p4", p4.getText().toString());
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

And here is my code from Activity 2:

```
public class FourCalculate extends Activity {

   class Calculate {
    public String Name;
    public int Scor;

    public Calculate(String sName, int iScor) {
        this.Name = sName;
        this.Scor = iScor;
    }
}


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_four_calculate);

        // Names
        TextView place1final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1);
        place1final.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name1"));
        String name1final;
        name1final = place1final.getText().toString();

        TextView place2final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place2);
        place2final.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name2"));
        String name2final;
        name2final = place2final.getText().toString();

        TextView place3final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place3);
        place3final.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name3"));
        String name3final;
        name3final = place3final.getText().toString();

        TextView place4final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place4);
        place4final.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name4"));
        String name4final;
        name4final = place4final.getText().toString();

        // Scores
        TextView place1finalscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1score);
        place1finalscore.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("p1"));
        String score1final;
        score1final = place1finalscore.getText().toString();

        TextView place2finalscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place2score);
        place1finalscore.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("p2"));
        String score2final;
        score2final = place2finalscore.getText().toString();

        TextView place3finalscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place3score);
        place3finalscore.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("p3"));
        String score3final;
        score3final = place3finalscore.getText().toString();

        TextView place4finalscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place4score);
        place4finalscore.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("p4"));
        String score4final;
        score4final = place4finalscore.getText().toString();

        int finalscore1;
        finalscore1 = Integer.parseInt(score1final);

        int finalscore2;
        finalscore2 = Integer.parseInt(score2final);

        int finalscore3;
        finalscore3 = Integer.parseInt(score3final);

        int finalscore4;
        finalscore4 = Integer.parseInt(score4final);

        ArrayList<FourCalculate> arrFourCalculate = new ArrayList<>(4);


        //building manually the array list
        arrFourCalculate.add(new Calculate(name1final, finalscore1));
        arrFourCalculate.add(new Calculate(name2final, finalscore2));  
        arrFourCalculate.add(new Calculate(name3final, finalscore3)); 
        arrFourCalculate.add(new Calculate(name4final, finalscore4)); 

        Collections.sort(arrFourCalculate, new Comparator<FourCalculate>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(FourCalculate o1, FourCalculate o2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(o1.Scor).compareTo(o2.Scor);
            }

        });

       place1final.setText(String.valueOf(arrFourCalculate.get(3)));
       place2final.setText(String.valueOf(arrFourCalculate.get(2)));
       place3final.setText(String.valueOf(arrFourCalculate.get(1)));
       place4final.setText(String.valueOf(arrFourCalculate.get(0)));
    }
}
```

After i enter names and numbers, App crashes when i try to reach Activity 2.
Logcat:

```
07-23 18:32:26.416 12392-12392/com.example.sante.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.sante.myapplication, PID: 12392
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sante.myapplication/com.example.sante.myapplication.FourCalculate}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                                                                                 at com.example.sante.myapplication.FourCalculate.onCreate(FourCalculate.java:79)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Post some code if you want people to help you. There is 1000 ways to achieve this

Comment: App crashes? That does not help us to identify the problem.

Comment: What could help? What is missing?

Comment: Post the error message you get when you try to navigate to activity 2

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems pretty clear about whats happening here. You ***CAN NOT*** instantiate an Activity, so this:

```
public FourCalculate (String sName, int iScor) {
        this.Name = sName;
        this.Scor = iScor;
    }
```

and this:

```
arrFourCalculate.add(new FourCalculate(name1final, finalscore1)); 
arrFourCalculate.add(new FourCalculate(name2final, finalscore2)); 
arrFourCalculate.add(new FourCalculate(name3final, finalscore3)); 
arrFourCalculate.add(new FourCalculate(name4final, finalscore4));
```

Can not be done. Create a separate Model Class for your object

Comment: Ive editet my code and getting new error when debugging. I Cant figure out what im doing wrong.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""; means you are trying to do this `Integer.parseInt("");`, one of your arguments is empty

Answer (score 0):

Finaly! With some help I achieved what i want. Sharing correct code.

```
public class FourCalculate extends Activity {

    class Calculate {

        public String Name;
        public int Scor;

        public Calculate(String sName, int iScor) {
            this.Name = sName;
            this.Scor = iScor;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Name + " " + Scor;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_four_calculate);

        // Names
        TextView place1final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place1);
        place1final.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name1"));
        String name1final;
        name1final = place1final.getText().toString();

        TextView place2final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place2);
        place2final.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name2"));
        String name2final;
        name2final = place2final.getText().toString();

        TextView place3final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place3);
        place3final.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name3"));
        String name3final;
        name3final = place3final.getText().toString();

        TextView place4final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place4);
        place4final.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name4"));
        String name4final;
        name4final = place4final.getText().toString();

        String finalscore1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("p1");
        String finalscore2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("p2");
        String finalscore3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("p3");
        String finalscore4 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("p4");


        finalscore1 = finalscore1.length() > 0 ? finalscore1 : "0";
        finalscore2 = finalscore2.length() > 0 ? finalscore2 : "0";
        finalscore3 = finalscore3.length() > 0 ? finalscore3 : "0";
        finalscore4 = finalscore4.length() > 0 ? finalscore4 : "0";

        ArrayList<Calculate> arrFourCalculate = new ArrayList<>(4);


        arrFourCalculate.add(new Calculate(name1final, Integer.parseInt(finalscore1)));
        arrFourCalculate.add(new Calculate(name2final, Integer.parseInt(finalscore2)));
        arrFourCalculate.add(new Calculate(name3final, Integer.parseInt(finalscore3)));
        arrFourCalculate.add(new Calculate(name4final, Integer.parseInt(finalscore4)));


        Collections.sort(arrFourCalculate, new Comparator<Calculate>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Calculate o1, Calculate o2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(o1.Scor).compareTo(o2.Scor);
            }

        });

       place1final.setText(String.valueOf(arrFourCalculate.get(3)));
       place2final.setText(String.valueOf(arrFourCalculate.get(2)));
       place3final.setText(String.valueOf(arrFourCalculate.get(1)));
       place4final.setText(String.valueOf(arrFourCalculate.get(0)));
    }
}
```